# how do I restrict user search?

Tags: php, mysql

I do have a PHP search engine and many people are using it. what I want to do is when some one search more than 25 times then give him a warning say you have exceeded todays limit and no further saerch is allowed.

How can I do that with PHP mysql? or is it better to use cookies or session?? if so how it will do?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that?

Comment: a cookie / session can be deleted by the user, so it would be more of a soft limit, if you wanna be safe save the number of requests per ip and a timestamp in a table and act based on that, or if its not that big of a deal use some non persistent key-value store like APC (better for performance)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a table in MySQL with the user ID (or any other uniquely identifying information), a date representing the current day, and a counter field which you can increase by 1 every time he does a search. Then check the counter before initiating a search, and, if the counter is 25, don't allow the search.

Using sessions, APC, memcache, cookies, etc, does not guarantee that you will be able to hold the limit.

If you use APC or memcache or any other system designed for caching, your memory limit might run out and the key you stored will vanish, thus allowing the user 25 new searches.

If you use the session, the user can simply log out and log in again and get 25 new searches.

If you use cookies, the user can simply alter or remove the cookie from the browser, thus allowing new searches again.

Never trust the user or a caching system.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with cookies, however:

1. Cookies can only identify 1 browser on 1 computer.
2. Cookies can be deleted.

So, all a user would need to do is change browsers, computers, or clear his/her cookies, and they have a fresh set of searches.

You could do it with a session variable, however:

1. Unless you're explicitly setting the expiration of the session, it will end once the browser closes.

So, all a user would need to do is close and re-open the browser, and then they'd have a new set of searches.

Thus, the "stickiest" option is to store an incremental count of searches in a database, however:

1. Users would have to be logged in / create an account in order to search, otherwise you'd have to rely upon IP addresses to identify users, which isn't 100% reliable and may be too coarse for your needs.

Nonetheless, this is still probably the best option.

There are many ways you could design and implement the database schema, and honestly how you do it will really depend on *exactly* how many users + user-searches you have going each day.

But, the basic algorithm (regardless of database design) would be:

1. Website: User logs in / creates an account
2. MySQL: A new user record is created
3. Website: User performs a search
4. MySQL: Check to make sure that the user is not over his/her limit for the day

   1. (TRUE) MySQL: Return an error message
   2. (FALSE) MySQL: Perform search and return results
5. Website: Display error message or results

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if ( isset($_POST['q']) ) { // insert your query parameter instead of 'q'
    // Determine if the search counter exists
    if (isset( $_SESSION['search_counter'] ) ) {
        if ( $_SESSION['search_counter'] > 25 ) {
            // Rate-limit message here
        }
    }
    else {
        // Create a session key to hold the search counter.
        $_SESSION['search_counter'] = 0;
    }
    // Increment the counter after every search.
    $_SESSION['search_counter']++;
}
```

Comment: You'd want to initialize to 0, since you increment immediately afterwards

Answer (score 0):

If these users are not logged in storing the data in a server-side session is the most reliable way, as cookies can be easily cleared. But even that can be circumvented. If it's really a big issue - have them authenticate and then tie this data to their session and user information on the server, so if it's cleared you can double check the database and then allow them to perform the action. This will inhibit performance, so your mileage may vary.